# Have Pathfinder's designers explained the lack of prepared, fast-progression, Charisma-based spellcasters?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class, designer-reasons

Wizard, cleric, druid, witch, and shaman all have similar spellcasting mechanics.  They have the fastest spell progression (i.e., access to a new spell level at each odd-numbered class level), which means they are the first to get 9th level spells.  They are also all prepared casters, meaning that they have the widest spell selection.  As a result, they are often considered the [most powerful](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=11990.0) spellcasting classes.  Some of them may use Charisma for class features, but their primary casting abilities are either Intelligence or Wisdom.

Where, if at all, has Paizo (or its designers) ever explained why there are no similar spellcasters that use Charisma as their primary casting ability?  Is this an intentional choice meant to balance the mechanical advantages between classes?  Or have they suggested any plans to implement such a class in future content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### No, they have not.

However, the [Ultimate Intrigue](http://paizo.com/paizo/blog/v5748dyo5likr&page=5?The-Most-Intriguing-Classes#215) introduced us to the [Feyspeaker](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid/archetypes/paizo---druid-archetypes/feyspeaker-druid-archetype/) druid archetype.

The feyspeaker uses her Charisma score instead of her Wisdom score as her key spellcasting ability score (to determine her spell DCs, bonus spells per day, concentration checks, and so on).

That makes the Feyspeaker the (currently) only 9-level Charisma-based prepared spellcaster on the game, along with the [Paladin](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin/), which is a 4-level Charisma-based prepared spellcaster.

So, it's not like they have a bias against the idea, but i believe they simply want to create an *identity* to each ability. We also don't have many [Intelligence-based](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor/archetypes/inquisitor-archetypes---paizo/living-grimoire-inquisitor-archetype/) [divine casters](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/occult-adventures/occult-classes/occultist/archetypes/paizo-llc---occultist-archetypes/reliquarian-occultist-archetype/).

Comment: Interesting.  What you mean by "identity"?

Comment: *Class identity* is a term that is vaguely used to define certain arquetypes within the game system, as to fill a certain fantasy role. Like, wizards cast spells, fighters are good at hitting things, rogues are sneaky, and so on. Here, im using the term *identity* in a similar fashion.